# Easiest way to copy development SQL Server to thumb drive

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, backup, replication

I have a small SQL database that is on my development PC only. I'd like to make frequent backup copies of it to a thumb drive. If I could have it do it automatically on a schedule when the thumb drive is detected, that'd be even better. What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did to get the database and other folders to automatically sync to my USB drive every time I plug it in:

1. Install [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155) made by Microsoft.

   - Add a folder pair to copy from the DB folder to the USB drive.
   - Filter files to only the files you want to copy.
2. Create a batch program with the content below called SyncMe.bat and save it on your USB drive
3. Open Event Viewer from the Control Panel.
4. Navigate to Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows DriverFrameworks-UserMode > Operational
5. Clear the log to make it easier to find the right events.
6. Plug in the USB drive.
7. Refresh the log, find the latest event that is specific to that USB drive, right-click, and Attach Task To This Event.
8. Add an action that runs the SyncMe.bat program you created

SyncMe.bat contents (update to reflect your paths and file names):

```
@echo off

if exist "G:\SyncMe.bat" goto fileexists

goto nofile

:fileexists
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE" -S computername\instancename -E -n -Q "master..sp_detach_db 'DatabaseName'"
"C:\Program Files\SyncToy 2.1\SyncToyCmd.exe" -R
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\OSQL.EXE" -S computername\instancename -E -n -Q "master..sp_attach_db 'DatabaseName', 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.InstanceName\MSSQL\DATA\DatabaseName.mdf','C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.InstanceName\MSSQL\DATA\LogName_log.ldf'"
goto end

:nofile
echo SyncMe.bat not found on G:\
goto end

:end
```

Comment: Hopefully, no one else plugs in a USB drive :)

Comment: I still have to test that, but I picked an event ID that looks specific to my USB device so hopefully that won't be a problem. I suppose I could always wrap the call to SyncToy in a batch program that checks for the existence of a unique file on the USB drive before it runs.

Comment: There, I updated my answer to include a batch program that checks for the existence of itself on the USB drive before syncing. So there should be no danger of plugging in a different USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is copy the .mdf and .ldf files, if you didn't change any settings you should be able to find them around here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

I don't think you can do that while the server is running, but you can detach a DB easiliy from Management Studio (right-click database .. tasks .. detach). Then you can copy the files for sure, zipping them first should make a lot of difference in size and easy to version them.

The other way around, in management studio you can select the databases node, and richtclick .. attach database to attach them again.

[This](http://www.petri.co.il/move-db-files-in-sql-server-taking-db-offline.htm) seems like a good article on the matter.

Regards Gert-Jan

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get SQL Server to do this all for you.  I'd end up writing a little console app that used [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) to do the work for me:

```
Server sqlServer = new Server(@"MYMACHINE\INSTANCENAME");
sqlServer.DetachDatabase("MyDatabaseName", false);

// copy the mdf and ldf to your thumb drive

StringCollection databaseFiles = new StringCollection();
databaseFiles.Add(@"C:\MyDBLoc\MyDatabase.mdf");
databaseFiles.Add(@"C:\MyDBLoc\MyDatabase.ldf");
sqlServer.AttachDatabase("MyDatabaseName", databaseFiles);
```